# What is the growth rate of the world wide web?

Tags: computer-networks

Is there any way to estimate how much data is added to the world wide web each second? Are there any studies about this?

Comment: try looking at ["how much does the internet weigh?"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/internet/8865093/Internet-weighs-the-same-as-a-strawberry.html), although not an answer, it might give you some direction for estimations.

Comment: http://www.worldwidewebsize.com/. More seriously, I think Albert-Laszlo Barabasi has done work in this topic.

Comment: [A meta-discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/359/41) about the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is much interesting research in this area that is ongoing. See eg

- Using search engines to estimate size based on pages counted eg [How Large is the WWW](http://www.stat.washington.edu/adobra/Files/Papers/Webpaper.pdf) by Dobra and Fienberg
- Theoretical models of networks that model the growth of the web and reflect its [small world graph structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network) eg [Models for the Growth of the Web by Ho, Pu, Tsiatas](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~atsiatas/models.pdf)